# CMS Как сделать sql запрос для перемещения выбранного ряда поверх либо ниже другого?

Tags: php, sql

Как сделать sql запрос для перемещения выбранного ряда поверх либо ниже другого?

Есть стрелки по которым нажимаешь и и этот ряд перемещается наверх при клике на стрелку вверх, тоесть меняются местами ряда

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: создай поле по которому будешь сортировать, если его нет. И при нажатии на стрелочку меняй значение этого поля для соответствующей строки

Comment: @md5hash , как правило, нужно менять не у одной строки, а еще и у той, с которой меняешь местами

Comment: @Герман Борисов, согласен!